# get rid of a nasty widow

Tags: widows-orphans

I am currently doing the "fine-tuning" to a finished document *(scrbook, flushbottom, other information from preamble does not seem to be helpful here)*. Everything fine, but on one page I have an annoying widow line, see picture.

[image: Widow line marked in red. Note that the page displayed left is actually odd and the right one is even]

Widow line marked in red. Note that the page displayed left is actually odd and the right one is even. So I should really get rid of it.

Simply applying `\looseness=-1` to the second paragraph of the first of the two pages will not help, as a two-lined footnote is at the end of the paragraph.

The first paragraph on the first of these two pages almost fills it's last line, so adding `\looseness=1` here seems to be a good solution. However, when I do this, the following happens:

[image: Line did not move]

As you can see, the first paragraph is enlarged, but LaTeX uses the additional line to fill the former space above the footnotes, and does not move the additional line to the next page which looks like in the image above (that would be my intention).

So, what do I have to do to preserve the space above of the footnotes on that page? Increasing the `\widowpenalty` value does not seem to be a good option, as it is global and i just need something for this one paragraph.

Comment: You could use a group around the change of `\widowpenalty`.

Comment: It seems that `\enlargethispage` would do.

Comment: ´\enlargethispage´does not do, but moves also the footnotes

Comment: group around `\widowpenalty` , so just {} will do?

Comment: @scienceponder: The problem is your orphan has a footnote following it, and that footnote cannot fit on the same page if the orphan was brought to the previous page. Try managing the footnote with a separate `\footnotemark` ... `\footnotetext` pair.

Comment: @werner: yes i know, that's why I want to move the prior line to the next page.

Comment: If you use `scrbook` then you can fix the textblock dimensions easily with the `typearea`package (instead of geometry). A `DIV=calc` option in the `\documentclass` could improve the page, your lines look quite long for the type size and the paper size. Fix it before and later you can play with the `widowpenalty` values for solve your problem.

Comment: @scienceponder: Do you have any footnotes in the "prior line"? If not, issue `\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}` somewhere on that page, which should shove an additional line over to the following page (where the current orphan resides).

Comment: @Aradnix: DIV and typearea was set like this by intention. I know that It is not "good typoghraphy" but I have to follow some guidelines about how much text on one page.

Comment: @werner: no I don't have and as said in my first comment `\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}` does not only move the line, to the next page, but also changes the lower border of the footnote area.

Comment: @scienceponder: Then it's not clear what your exact, expected output should resemble... at least not to me.

Comment: @werner: the output should be exactly like what you think, but with the blank space between the last line and the footnotes which you can see on the first picture, and not with footnotes moved up.

Comment: it is very hard to answer as you have posted no example  if you want the last line of the fist page to go to the top of the second page, just add `\pagebreak` anywhere in the previous line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare with and without `\pagebreak`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength\textheight{-20\baselineskip}
\def\a{\stepcounter{enumi}\roman{enumi} one two three four five six. }
\def\b{\a\a\a\a Red blue yellow green black white. \a\a}
\def\c{\a\b\a\b\b}

\begin{document}

\c this\footnote{and that}

\c\b
%\pagebreak
\a\a\a  this\footnote{\b}

\c
\end{document}
```